# Beacon Broadcasting with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, beacon, altbeacon, eddystone

In the app I'm wiriting I am trying to broadcast an Eddystone UID Beacon. To do so I have implemented the package beacon_broadcast (https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast) and adapted the given example Code (basically changed the layout and manufacturer ID) to the following:

```
beaconBroadcast
    .setUUID('39ED98FF-2900-441A-802F-9C398FC199D2')
    .setMajorId(1)
    .setMinorId(100)
    .setLayout('s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19')
    .setManufacturerId(0x001D)
    .start();
```

When I try to start broadcasting I get the following error message:

> E/MethodChannel#pl.pszklarska.beaconbroadcast/beacon_state(22561): Failed to handle method call
> E/MethodChannel#pl.pszklarska.beaconbroadcast/beacon_state(22561): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beacon has 3 identifiers but format requires 2
> E/MethodChannel#pl.pszklarska.beaconbroadcast/beacon_state(22561):  at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser.getBeaconAdvertisementData(BeaconParser.java:633)
> E/MethodChannel#pl.pszklarska.beaconbroadcast/beacon_state(22561):  at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(BeaconTransmitter.java:179)

Now, is there something I am overlooking? Unfortunately I am not overly familiar with all the Bluetooth stuff yet.